# Origin of "smooth operator"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I'm interested in the origin of the term *smooth operator*. Does anyone know where it came from? What kind of operation?

Comment: In a non-mathematical sense, I presume?

Comment: Oh great, now I've got the Sade song stuck in my head. Thanks a heap.

Comment: Do you think it could be associated with Jacob in the bible book of Genesis. He swindled his brother, and Scripture refers to himself as a "smooth Man." I'm not suggesting that Jacob called himself a "con-man," but perhaps this descriptive title "smooth operator" came from this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word *operator* has had several slang meanings over time, according to the Oxford English Dictionary. A brief list of the time and definition of *operator* is:

> **1598**: A person who performs a surgical operation or operations; an operating surgeon or dentist.
>
> **1611**: A person who deals in quack medicines, etc. Obs.
>
> **1704**: A person who commits fraudulent operations; a thief, a pickpocket.
>
> **1828**:  A person who carries on (speculative) financial operations. Also: a person adept at speculative or shrewd operations; (formerly) a person who acts in a cunning or underhand manner.
>
> **1838**: A person who or company which runs a business, enterprise, etc.
>
> **1944**: A person with a talent for seduction; a smooth talker.

The phrase *smooth operator* starts to appear in the late 1890s. For example, in ["The Strange Schemes of Randolph Mason"](https://books.google.com/books?id=IuKqiY72GEEC&pg=PA211&dq=%22smooth+operator%22&hl=en&ei=c2iTTp_JNMzq0QG2mpAl&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22smooth%20operator%22&f=false), it says:

> [image]

Here, a *smooth operator* is someone who is "smooth" at running a business or set of financial operations (the senses from the earlier 1800s). This is not the only application of *smooth operator*. In the 1980s, the OED notes the following usage:

> **1980**    Photo-Love Summer Spectacular 7/1   You're quite a smooth operator, what with names and telephone numbers just like that!

The "operation" has changed over time. In the 1700 and 1800s, the "operation" was financial--it referred to either theft operations, speculating on stocks (*operate* as a verb meant "To deal or speculate in stocks or shares; to buy and sell commodities as a broker"), or business operations. Then, in the 1900s, the "operations" referred to the "business" of playing at courtship and seducing women.

Thus, now a *smooth operator* can refer to the "business" of financial operations or seduction operations, with *smooth* modifying *operator* in a primarily (and possibly solely) negative way.

Answer (score 2):

The OED’s earliest citation for those actual words is dated 1980. However, a 1944 citation has '*Big-time operator*, a slick chick's smooth fellow', itself a quotation from a slang dictionary of the time. Chambers Slang Dictionary defines ‘operator’ alone as ‘a successful seducer of women’ and dates it to the 1940s.

Comment: [Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=smooth+operator&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=smooth+operator&hl=en&safe=active&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&sa=X&ei=a6WJTrnrCMGsiAeHjsm8Dw&ved=0CBkQpwUoAw&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=714e2c23287e9f2&biw=1280&bih=647) shows examples from 1896

Answer (score 1):

On PBS American Experience program about the Gilded Age and immigration during that period in American History.  A "Smooth Operator" referred to a person who could operate a telegraph key with skill (a steady hand and speed)

Comment: Did the program explain why “smooth” was used in this context?

Comment: Near the beginning of the episode, historian Jackson Lears says of Andrew Carnegie when he started an early job as a telegraph operator, "He is a smooth operator, which is a term that was used for guys who worked for Western Union who could tap out Morse code very smoothly."

Answer (score 0):

From the movie The Best Years of Our Lives.  Al is talking to his daughter about Fred and refers to him as a smooth operator.  Google it.